# Running WordPress with no database

Tags: database, wordpress

I was looking for a way to configure WordPress to run using only a filesystem database.

Sort of like H2 in Java, or in memory. Anyone?

Just for demonstration purposes

Answer (score 4):

Not possible, one of the requirements for Wordpress is MySQL: http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

If you just need a site for demos, you can run a local instance of MySQL pretty easily using [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) on Windows (and technically Mac too), but I prefer [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) for Mac.

Comment: Not as far as I know, there is quite a bit of MySQL specific code. In various forum discussions the core contributors have questioned the need for supporting more than MySQL given its ubiquity.

Comment: If you are not worried about wordpress and its plugins, you can go with a flat file cms like Pico