# Run wordpress site without mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to know how to run wordpress site without mysql because mysql causing high cpu load. If any one have solution then please share it. Share any alternative solution. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running wordpress with no database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238308/running-wordpress-with-no-database)

Comment: With respect, you're giving us an x-for-y problem to solve here. Your "y" problem is an overload on your MySQL database. You're offering "x" as "get rid of MySQL." That's not going to happen:WordPress is inextricably tied up with MySQL.   Why not try to solve your "y" problem: your MySQL overload?  Some choices: (a) Ask your hosting provider for help, if you have one and they're competent (I know, the second is rare).  (b) Migrate your WordPress installation to WordPress.com or wpengine.com or some other high-grade provider. (c) Troubleshoot your MySQL problems yourself.

Comment: Ported a site over to a new provider, except for the sql db. All of the pages in the site can be _viewed_ at least, forget about posting or any configurations though. Plugins that depend on db records will bomb.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Wordpress is completely based on all page and post data as well as all kinds of settings being stored in and fetched from a database.

Comment: Not only *a database,*, but specifically a MySQL database. (MariaDB is a MySQL variant.)

Comment: @O.Jones not quite: https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/ : *MySQL version 5.6 or greater OR MariaDB version 10.0 or greater*

Answer (score 1):

You might(!) be able to replace MySQL with another database with a lot(!) of effort, but MySQL shouldn't have any trouble handling a simple WordPress site.

If you have plugins or theme-code that does a lot of database queries, your time will be better spent optimizing on that side of the equation.

Also, add caching to take load off the system in general.